# How to call java method in xml attribute

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, ehcache

In the XML below, I want to set `Math:random()` as the value for the `name` attribute:

```
<ehcache name="common.cache" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">
```

I tried in below way but it's not working:

```
<ehcache  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:Math="http://www.math.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:math="xalan://java.lang.Math" name="math:random()"
  extension-element-prefixes="math" exclude-result-prefixes="math"  
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">
```

What is the syntax for invoking the `Math:random()` method and setting that value for the name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not supported by the XML configuration of Ehcache.
And I would advise strongly against using such a naming scheme with the programatic API.

The cache name is used to look up caches from the cache manager in order to access them. It is also used internally for identifying potential on disk cache files if configured with a disk tier.

In short your cache naming scheme should be stable and not random.